# How to load image in Flask from database?

Tags: python, mysql, flask, binary

I'm a newbie to the Flask and trying to load a image which stored in my database type of Binary like this:

```
avatar_local = db.Column(db.LargeBinary(1024*1024))
```

now how to show it in a html file?
this is my file and it can't work correctly:
`<img class="img-rounded profile-thumbnail" src="{{ user.avatar_local }}">`

I got wrong message：

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

This is my upload function, it works fine:

```
@main.route('/upload', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_avatar():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file']
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            current_user.avatar_local = file.read()
            db.session.add(current_user)
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect(url_for('main.user_page', username=current_user.username))
    return render_template('upload_avatar.html', user=current_user)
```

Comment: Typo in your HTML. Should be `src={{ user.avatar_local }}`, not `gavatar_local`.

Comment: sorry,it's just a mistake in here.@mprat